# Output 4:3 video on old Apple TV?

Tags: appletv

I have an old Apple TV that I have hooked up to my 4:3 TV, and I would like to have the output from the Apple TV match the ratio of my TV so there isn't any stretching or squishing. It's running the latest firmware 3.0.2.

Comment: Are there letterbox settings on the TV itself? Apple TV can output 480p which should be (but not necessarily be) a 4:3 ratio. Can you set the output setting on your Apple TV?

Comment: You can read how to change the output (select a video mode) in the manual which you can download. Then read page 30. ( http://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=answerlink&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmanuals.info.apple.com%2Fen_US%2FAppleTV_SetupGuide.pdf&answerid=16777216&src=support_site.home.search )

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe it will be 4:3. One of the requirements for ATV was a widescreen TV. I think it always assumes a 16:9 ratio. As @matthewpavkov suggested, best bet would be to get the tele to force the input into 4:3, but it's very model dependant if the tele actually supports that.

Update: I stand corrected, there seems to be a thread related to this exact issue on the MacRumors fourms http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=658621 However, it seems that it stopped working on the 3.x firmware, so there's an even more hacky way of achieving it here. Sounds horrible though! http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=811425